# She turned me into a newt, but I got better

Tags: expressions, jokes

From Monty Python and the holy grail:

> BEDEVERE: What makes you think she is a witch?
>
> VILLAGER #3: Well, she turned me into a newt.
>
> BEDEVERE: A newt?
>
> VILLAGER #3: I got better.

[image]

How does this joke work? I think a newt is some kind of water dwelling salamander, surely that isn't meant here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course the amphibian is meant here.

She turned me into a newt.  (Something an alleged witch might do.  More commonly a frog, but that is the idea.)

But (obviously) I am looking at you and you are not a newt.  How do you explain that?  "I got better."

Comment: Oh, that's embarrassingly straightforward. The confusing thing for me was that the German translation is really quite different. They added sexual innuendo to that scene and I expected it to be in the original as well.

Comment: Monty Python used the joke about "got/getting better" several times in the movie. @lhk,  most notably in the "Bring out your dead" sketch.

Comment: @Cascabel and the 'I feel fine' trope, which is in the 'bring out your dead' and the 'swamp castle' scenes.